# Visualisation of ${\Bbb Z}/3{\Bbb Z}$-torsors of $S^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology, principal-bundles

For the circle $S^1$, we shall consider the ${\Bbb Z}/3{\Bbb Z}$-torsors. I know the isomorphism class of ${\Bbb Z}/3{\Bbb Z}$-torsors are classified by $H^1(S^1, {\Bbb Z}/3{\Bbb Z}) = {\mathrm{Hom}}(\pi_1(S^1), {\Bbb Z}/3{\Bbb Z}) = {\mathrm{Hom}}({\Bbb Z}, {\Bbb Z}/3{\Bbb Z}) = {\Bbb Z}/3{\Bbb Z}$.

I would like to realise these three torsors as visible manifolds which are non-isomorphic to each other. Apparently, $0 \in {\Bbb Z}/3{\Bbb Z}$ corresponds to the three disjoint union of $S^1$'s. I try to realise the ${\Bbb Z}/3{\Bbb Z}$-torsor of $S^1$ corresponding to $1 \in {\Bbb Z}/3{\Bbb Z}$.

My first attempt is to put some *exotic* structure to the connected Galois covering $Y \to S^1$, where ${\mathrm{Gal}}(Y/S^1) \cong {\Bbb Z}/3{\Bbb Z}$. Because $\pi(S^1) \cong {\Bbb Z}$, $Y$ is uniquely determined. Locally over $S^1$, $Y$ has three connected components which are disjoint from each other. I wish if $Y$ itself would be a ${\Bbb Z}/3{\Bbb Z}$-torsor. However, I know this is wrong, for there is no information of the character $\chi \colon \pi_1(S^1) \to {\Bbb Z}/3{\Bbb Z}$ added in the construction $Y$ which is a mere Galois covering. That is, $Y$ is actually a manifold, but cannot be a ${\Bbb Z}/3{\Bbb Z}$-torsor.

Q. What are connected manifolds other than $Y$ realised as ${\Bbb Z}/3{\Bbb Z}$-torsors of $S^1$?

Comment: I don't know the algebro-geometric side, but it looks to me the local picture should be as you describe (three points _with a distinguished cyclic ordering_ over each point of $S^1$), and lifting the path $t\mapsto e^{it}$ in $S^1$ joins $0$ to $0$ (trivial), to $1$, or to $2$. The non-trivial torsors have total space $S^1$; the non-trivial structure is encoded by the _projection maps_ to the base $S^1$, or (if you prefer) by their monodromy.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I would think the torsor corresponding to 1 should be the triple cover $S^1 \to S^1$, $z \mapsto z^3$; and then the torsor structure has 1 act as $z \mapsto e^{2\pi i/3} z$.

Comment: Or alternatively, maybe visualize the torsor as being contained in a torus circling a copy of $S^1$ in the $xy$-plane: the torsor corresponding to 1 would be $\{ (\theta, \phi) \mid 3\phi \equiv \theta \pmod{2\pi} \}$ (as opposed to the trivial torsor being isomorphic to $\{ (\theta, \phi) \mid 3\phi \equiv 0 \pmod{2\pi} \} = \{ (\theta, \phi) \mid \phi \in \{ 1, e^{2\pi i/3}, e^{4\pi i/3} \}$).

Comment: Great thanks. Pierre

Comment: > The non-trivial torsors have total space S1; the non-trivial structure is encoded by the > projection maps to the base S1,   In this context, how can I prove that there is no continuous map between f: Y_1 → Y_2 over S^1, where Y_1 and Y_2 have different projections onto S^1?

Comment: If there is no continuous commutative diagram over S^1 between Y_1 and Y_2, this fact for sure ensures that Y_1 and Y_2 are different torsors.

Comment: According to Mr. A. D. Hwang's comment, the two *projections* are different. Suppose $p_1 \colon X \to S^1$ and $p_2 \colon X \to S^1$, where $X$ is a Galois cover of $S^1$ of degree three. Then is it true that there is no continuous morphism $f \colon X \to X$ over $S^1$?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\Ints}{\mathbf{Z}}$The diagram shows the two non-trivial $\Ints/3\Ints$ torsors. The total space of each is a circle, divided into thirds. Each third is color-coded consistently, the base circle is in the middle, and the projection mappings are the obvious "squeezings" of the fibres to points, which send each arc onto the base circle.

[image: The two non-trivial Z/3Z torsors]

The mapping carrying one torsor to the other in your linked question may be viewed as a suitable involution of the total space, e.g., complex conjugation of the unit circle in the complex plane, a.k.a. the inverse mapping $z = e^{i\theta} \mapsto \overline{z} = e^{-i\theta} = \frac{1}{z}$.